# azure data factory v2 copy data activity recursive

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I am new to azure Data factory v2

I have a folder having 2 files F1.csv and F2.csv in a blob storage.

I have a created a copy data pipeline activity to load the data from file to a table in azure DWH with 3 parameters and copy recursively was made to false.

Parameter1: container

Parameter2: directory

Parameter3: F1.csv

executed successfully when used the above parameters for the copy data activity.

But the data has been loaded from two files, only one file has given as parameter for the activity

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the "wildcard file name" parameter ( Select the pipeline and look under the source tab )  ?

If it is set as  *.*  please remove that and it should work .